# Is there a query formula in spreadsheets where if the date in the column matches todays date, it pulls the values from the rows within that column?

Tags: google-sheets

In the picture M3 is today's date. Is there a formula that will automatically pull data from M8 (same column) since M3's date matches today and place it in another, unrelated cell? The closest I can get is a where function with a query, but I could not get it to work.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet for extra fast answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(8, MATCH(TODAY(), 3:3, 0)))
```

Comment: You're awesome.